# How to compare 2 Arrays to update key value pairs in one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a main array of tags

```
var tagsArray = [
    {
        name: "1",
        selected: undefined
    },
    {
        name: "2",
        selected: undefined
    },
    {
        name: "3",
        selected: undefined
    }
]
```

Then an array of selected tags to compare it to:

```
var selectedTags = [
    {
        name: "1",
        selected: true
    }
]
```

How would you run some kind of comparison (for-loop) to check what objects in `selectedTags` have the `selected: true` value?

Then also set the same object's `selected` value in `tagsArray` to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an access map, then iterate and find the `true` values and set the values in the other array

```
var map = {};

tagsArray.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    map[obj.name] = index;
});

selectedTags.forEach(function(obj) {
    if ( obj.selected ) {
        tagsArray[map[obj.name]].selected = true;
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5arxu32j/)

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about `map`, this is so clean, I was trying to get this to work with a couple of for-loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use 2 for-loops and it doesn't look much worse in terms of code or clarity. But on average it will run slower O(n^2) than using map.

```
var i,j;

for(i = 0; i < tagsArray.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < selectedTags.length; j++){
        if(tagsArray[i].name === selectedTags[j].name){
            tagsArray[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztyankov/1dv36qef/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I guess the `map` works the same way as a `switch-case` statement, in that it finds what it needs to find faster?

Comment: You're welcome! Maps are designed for fast data look up. So for example, instead of doing the whole inside loop to match a name from tagsArray to selectedTags array, it uses a different approach that uses less time to find the same match.