# Removing object from array in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

http://jsfiddle.net/0444046b/12/

I have a complex Array of objects, each object has it's own tag Array.

I also have just an object which should match one of the objects in the tag Array, and if so remove that tag.

[Got some help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29952458/how-to-compare-2-arrays-to-update-key-value-pairs-in-one), however my example there was too simple, so far no luck with this below.

Basically I have the object `tag` and I need to remove it from the `tags` Array inside of `tagsArray`.

```
var tagsArray = [{
        name: "group1",
        tags: [
            {
                name: "1",
                tag_id: "1234"
            },
            {
                name: "2",
                tag_id: "5678"
            },
            {
                name: "3",
                tag_id: "9012"
            }
         ]
},
{
    name: "group2",
    tags: []
}
];

console.log(tagsArray[0]);

// Need to find this inside of tags inside of tagsArray and remove it:
var tag = {
    name: "3",
    tag_id: "9012"
}

var temp_array = [];
temp_array.push(tag);

var map = {};

tagsArray.forEach(function(obj, index) {
    map[obj.tag_id] = index;
});

console.log(map);


temp_array.forEach(function(obj) {
    if ( obj.tag_id ) {
        tagsArray.splice(tagsArray[map[obj.tag_id]]);
        console.log(tagsArray);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of Daniel Imms is totally fine, but this one also can solve your problem, and it is a bit faster.

```js
var tagsArray = [{
  name: "group1",
  tags: [{
    name: "1",
    tag_id: "1234"
  }, {
    name: "2",
    tag_id: "5678"
  }, {
    name: "3",
    tag_id: "9012"
  }]
}, {
  name: "group2",
  tags: [{
    name: "4",
    tag_id: "1012"
  }]
}];

var removedTag = {
  name: "4",
  tag_id: "1012"
};

var message = 'Before:</br>' + JSON.stringify(tagsArray) + '</br></br>';

tagsArray.forEach(function(obj, i) {
  obj.tags.forEach(function(tag, j) {
    if (tag.tag_id === removedTag.tag_id && tag.name === removedTag.name) {
      obj.tags.splice(j, 1);
      return;
    }
  });
});

message += 'After:</br>' + JSON.stringify(tagsArray);

document.body.innerHTML = message
```

I tested with jsPerf and here is the [link](http://jsperf.com/remove-item-of-array) and here is the result.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Choosing this one, because it also solves my problem in development code. The `filter` was for some reason removing all my tag objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through each item in `tagsArray` and then filter our matching elements in the inner tags property.

```js
var tagsArray = [{
  name: "group1",
  tags: [{
    name: "1",
    tag_id: "1234"
  }, {
    name: "2",
    tag_id: "5678"
  }, {
    name: "3",
    tag_id: "9012"
  }]
}, {
  name: "group2",
  tags: []
}];

// Need to find this inside of tags inside of tagsArray and remove it:
var removeTag = {
  name: "3",
  tag_id: "9012"
}

var message = 'Before:<br>' + JSON.stringify(tagsArray) + '<br><br>';

tagsArray.forEach(function(element) {
  element.tags = element.tags.filter(function(tag) {
    return tag.name != removeTag.name && tag.tag_id != removeTag.tag_id;
  })
});

message += 'After:<br>' + JSON.stringify(tagsArray);
document.body.innerHTML = message
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work in jsfiddle, just don't understand why in my dev code it removes every single tag now :(